# Text independent of screen resolution in Unity?

Tags: c#, unity, resolution, text

I have the following code that depends on the resolution of the user's display:

```
void OnGUI()
{
    GUI.Label(new Rect(432, 525, 9000, 9000), ("Hello!"));
}
```

And of course, the location of the text changes in devices with different resolutions. How can I make the text independent of screen resolution in Unity?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is an intra-network [cross post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34498831/text-independent-of-screen-resolution-in-unity/34499009).

Answer (score 2):

You can use a canvas scaler and put UI text on it.

http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/script-CanvasScaler.html

http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/UI.Text.html

GUI.Label on the game screen is only for quick debug hacks as far as I know.

Answer (score 0):

I have a work around for this problem. Idea is to assign position in percentage instead of hard coded coordinates.

1- First find out your base resolution, on which further work will base on. Print `Screen.width` and `Screen.height`. In my case it is `428 x 321`.
2- Find out the percentage of current position with resolution. If I consider `GUI.Label(new Rect(50, 50, 300, 300), ("Hello!"));`, then it'd be `50.0f/428.0f` width percentage and `50.0f/321.0f` height percentage.
3- Now assign position w.r.t. these percentages. Like, `GUI.Label(new Rect((50.0f/428.0f) * Screen.width, (50.0f/321.0f) * Screen.height, 300, 300), ("Hello!"));`

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using a gui label, you could simply add a text object to your project hierarchy (Create->UI->Text).  This will automatically add a canvas object as well.  Changing the UI scale mode on your canvas scaler to *"Scale with Screen Size"* will make the UI scale based on the screen resolution.  You would then set the anchors/pivot of your text object depending on exactly how you want it to behave.

I recommend watching this series of videos by 3DBuzz on youtube.  It goes in depth about how to set up UIs in Unity.

https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLt_Y3Hw1v3QTEbh8fQV1DUOUIh9nF0k6c